# AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi BadRequestException: Invalid connectionId

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I am having Websocket API Gateway and I trying to send message to connections using the **ApiGatewayManagementApi**.

First I configure it:

```
 const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
    apiVersion: "2018-11-29",
    endpoint: connectionsUrl
  });
```

And this is the code for postToConnection()

```
try {
    const params = {
      ConnectionId: connection.connectionId,
      Data: JSON.stringify(data.payload)
    };


    console.log(params, connectionsUrl);
    //THIS PRINTS: { ConnectionId: 'ckd609nog0009sgp847cj3lgy', Data: '{}' } 
         https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/socket-test




      await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection(params).promise();
} catch (e) {
      console.error('APIGW Post To Connection ERROR:', e);
      if (e.statusCode == 410) {
        let res = await this.DisconnectConnection(connection.connectionId);
        if (res.isError()) {
          return ServiceResponse.Error(res.error)
        }
        return ServiceResponse.Error(res.error)
      } else {
        return ServiceResponse.Error({message: e.message});
      }
    }
```

The ERROR I am getting in the catch where I am logging it is:

**APIGW Post To Connection ERROR: BadRequestException: Invalid connectionId: ckd609nog0009sgp847cj3lgy
**

This is not stale connection. This use case is where I am connected to the WebSocket and I send message to socket, it  does something and returns results vie postToConnection Method.

What is the problem ?

Comment: my `connectionId` looks like this `Qb3XLfwjFiACHXQ=` , are you sure you pass the right `connectionId` value ?
+ make sure your `endpoint` is the right combination of ``${domainName}/${stage}``

Comment: That connectionId was generated when I was running the WebSocket  service offline  (localhost) with "serverless-offline-plugin" and the Error was that one above. When running deployed version of the WebSocket service everything runs perfectly

Comment: Hi ! 
I'm facing the same problem can you tell me how did you solved that ?